# Generate a set of random unique integers from an interval

Tags: r

I am trying to build some machine learning models,

so I need training data and a validation data

so suppose I have N number of examples, I want to select random x examples in a data frame.

For example, suppose I have 100 examples, and I need 10 random numbers, is there a way (to efficiently) generate 10 random INTEGER numbers for me to extract the training data out of my sample data?

I tried using a while loop, and slowly change the repeated numbers, but the running time is not very ideal, so I am looking for a more efficient way to do it.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 84):

[`sample`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) (or `sample.int`) does this:

```
sample.int(100, 10)
# [1] 58 83 54 68 53  4 71 11 75 90
```

will generate ten random numbers from the range 1–100. You probably want `replace = TRUE`, which samples with replacing:

```
sample.int(20, 10, replace = TRUE)
# [1] 10  2 11 13  9  9  3 13  3 17
```

More generally, `sample` samples `n` observations from a vector of arbitrary values.

Comment: thanks! let me try out your solution

- no, i need my training data to be unique, but thanks for the additional information!!

Comment: Also, @LowYiXiang, you might find `head` and `tail` useful here: `idx <- sample.int(100); train.idx <- head(idx, 10); test.idx <- tail(idx, -10);`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a hold-out sampling. This is usually done using probabilities. So if you have `n.rows` samples and want a fraction of `training.fraction` to be used for training, you may do something like this:

```
select.training <- runif(n=n.rows) < training.fraction
data.training <- my.data[select.training, ]
data.testing <- my.data[!select.training, ]
```

If you want to specify EXACT number of training cases, you may do something like:

```
indices.training <- sample(x=seq(n.rows), size=training.size, replace=FALSE) #replace=FALSE makes sure the indices are unique
data.training <- my.data[indices.training, ]
data.testing <- my.data[-indices.training, ] #note that index negation means "take everything except for those"
```

Answer (score 0):

from the `raster` package:

```
raster::sampleInt(242, 10, replace = FALSE)
##  95 230 148 183  38  98 137 110 188  39
```

This may fail if the limits are too large:

```
sample.int(1e+12, 10)
```